# Building docker image on Raspberry Pi 3B+ with python 3 and numpy, scipy, pillow and matplotlib fails

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian Buster. I am running a deep-learning app that uses tensorflow-lite runtime and other modules like pillow, numpy and matplotlib. I have been trying to build a docker container to distribute the app. I am finding it very challenging to build an image from Dockerfile with the required libraries and after having spent the weekend experimenting with different base images and researching the issue made little progress.

Here are the contents of Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

## There is more after this 
## to install tensorflow-lite runtime
## from copied-over .whl file.
## I have it left out 
## as I have yet to progress beyond this point.
```

I get: `ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.16.2`

Here is my requirements manifest:

```
numpy==1.16.2
paho-mqtt==1.5.1
picamera==1.13
Pillow==5.4.1
scipy==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.0.2
```

I got these specific versions from `pip freeze > requirements.txt` on the Pi where the app is working.

What I have tried:

1. Using different base images from docker hub, including one from balena for armv7 that matches the set-up on my Pi (i.e. Rasbian Buster with Python 3.7.4).
2. Pulling a docker image with numpy in it (`docker pull ellerbach/tensor_pillow_flask`) and trying to use it as the base image.
3. Using a different Raspberry Pi 3.

Still no progress. Appreciate your help. The full text of the error message is:

```
Step 4/5 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 6bee0e112272
Collecting numpy==1.16.2
  Downloading numpy-1.16.2.zip (5.1 MB)
[91m    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o8ypxup1/numpy_0ed49f4dc38649d790838c7f052a364a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o8ypxup1/numpy_0ed49f4dc38649d790838c7f052a364a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-tax52vej
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o8ypxup1/numpy_0ed49f4dc38649d790838c7f052a364a/
    Complete output (4 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-tax52vej/numpy.egg-info
    Running from numpy source directory.
    error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
    ----------------------------------------
[0m[91mWARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/8d/6345b4f32b37945fedc1e027e83970005fc9c699068d2f566b82826515f2/numpy-1.16.2.zip#sha256=6c692e3879dde0b67a9dc78f9bfb6f61c666b4562fd8619632d7043fb5b691b0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
[0m[91mERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.16.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0rc1, 1.20.0rc2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0rc1, 1.21.0rc2, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.21.2, 1.21.3, 1.21.4)
[0m[91mERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.16.2
[0m[91mWARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[0m
```

Comment: Can you curl https://pypi.org/project/numpy from your RPI?

Comment: @richardec Do you mean like so: `curl https://pypi.org/project/numpy`? That pulls an html page on the pi as well as from inside the docker container with `docker exec`. Hope I understood your suggestion correctly.

Comment: You did. I just wanted to make sure that the RPI could connect to PyPI.

Comment: Will you please paste the full output of `pip` into the question?

Comment: @richardec Done, thank you! I have also tried including `RUN pip install --upgrade pip` in the Dockerfile before the pip command and that also runs into problems. I modified `requirements.txt` to see if any of the other packages will install but no such luck.

Comment: Try running `pip install` with `sudo`: `RUN sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @richardec Returns `/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found`, thank you. Also tried sudo from the terminal prompt inside the docker container, gave `command not found`.

Comment: Can you try the standard Python base image?

Comment: @richardec Do you mean  `FROM python` in Dockerfile? The tensorflow-lite runtime is only available for few versions of Python, such as 3.7.  Sure, I will try and post an update. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @richardec This did the trick `FROM arm32v7/python:3.7.10-buster` although it was a trial-and-error process. Thank you for your suggestions. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working through a trial-and-error process with different base images until I found one that works. This did the job:

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7.10-buster

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

The requirements manifest has:

```
numpy==1.16.2
paho-mqtt==1.5.1
picamera==1.13
Pillow==5.4.1
scipy==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.0.2
```

To install tensorflow-lite runtime, I used pip installer inside docker container with a local copy of the '.whl' file from Google. I included this file in the app folder that is copied over per the  Dockerfile. Now I have a docker container with all pre-requisites satisfied.

Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Buster! I was going to suggest buster actually, based on a post I saw...